# How to set Java HOME for multiple Java versions on Mac

Tags: java, macos, java-home, macos-monterey

I use Java 8 and Java 17 versions in several projects and I want to set default Java HOME as Java 8. For this purpose, I add `.zshenv` file to my user folder and make its content like this:

```
# Java 8
export PATH=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/bin:$PATH
# sudo ln -sfn /usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk 


# Java 17
# export PATH=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@17/bin:$PATH


# Maven
export PATH=~/apache-maven-3.8.6/bin:$PATH


export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8)
# export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17)

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

However, I get some problems related to not being able to set Java Home properly. So, could you please clarify me on **how can I set Java paths and set Java8 default path using .zsh way8** ?

I use MacOS Monterey.

Comment: *However, I get some problems related to not being able to set Java Home properly.* What does ```/usr/libexec/java_home -v1.8```  print? If you use '17' why, I wonder, is that not '8'?

Comment: Use jEnv https://www.jenv.be/

Comment: @g00se It prints "no such file or directory: usr/libexec/java_home". So, any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: @March Thanks March, but at a beginner, I want to use native solutions using zsh. Any idea?

Comment: There should be a space before the version I think: ```/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8``` And did you omit the starting forward slash?

Comment: When I retry by `usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8` then I get `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home`. On the other hand, I also tried to change this line in .zshenv file from `export PATH=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8/bin:$PATH` to 
`export PATH=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home:$PATH`. Is that true?

Comment: And do I restart the Mac after each update on `.zshenv` file?

Comment: Use sdkman and its auto-env feature.

Comment: *Is that true?* You mean is that *right*? I would look to be, yes. But if there are already Mac tools for managing this kind of stuff, it would be worth looking at using them